# How to store integers (numberLong) in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to insert financial data into a collection, so I want to explicitely cast my Javascript numbers into NumberLongs. Unfortunately, the following doesn't work:

```
  var myValue = parseInt('13', 10);
  Finance.insert({
    bal1: NumberLong(myValue),
  });
```

What is the correct way to do this with Meteor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. 
As per my post on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/o_co6nRjoYU

I believe the casting on read issue was solved in 0.6.5, when Meteor upgraded the MongoDB Driver from 1.3.7 to 1.3.17.

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/HISTORY :

```
1.3.13 2013-07-31
- Added promoteLongs option for to allow for overriding the promotion of Longs to Numbers and return the actual Long.
```

And in http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html :

```
Db()
promoteLongs {Boolean, default:true}, when deserializing a Long will fit it into a Number if it’s smaller than 53 bits
```

I've checked and Meteor does indeed receive number back again.

Considering that :

- According to ECMA: "Note that all the positive and negative integers
  whose magnitude is no greater than 2^53 are representable in the
  Number type
- You *want* mongo to store as numberLong if it's indeed a long

... we should be good now :)

Comment: Note that this still doesn't allow us to explicitly cast to a numberLong, see git issue 1314: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1314

Answer (score 0):

```
var myValue = parseInt('13', 10);
Finance.insert({
    stats: {
        bal1: NumberLong(myValue)
    }
});
```

So long as `NumberLong()` exists as a method the above should work.  Mongo supports the number type you are looking for according to the docs.

Comment: Hi DigiLord, NumberLong sadly doesn't exists as a method, hence the error being thrown.